# Query to split data in a column into multiple columns using id in another column (pivot table; crosstab)

Tags: mysql, pivot, query

Database engine:

```
Server version: 10.2.16-MariaDB-10.2.16+maria~xenial mariadb.org binary distribution
```

I have a database table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `disktemp` (
  `sample_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sample_epoch` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diskid` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diskt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sample_epoch` (`sample_epoch`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The table contains years of data for the various disks in my server. The data looks a bit like this:

```
> SELECT * FROM disktemp WHERE sample_time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR  ORDER BY sample_epoch, host;
+---------------------+--------------+--------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+
| sample_time         | sample_epoch | host   | diskid                 | diskt | id                                |
+---------------------+--------------+--------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+
| 2018-07-30 16:10:01 |   1532959800 | boson  | wwn-0x50014ee261020fce |    47 | wwn-0x50014ee261020fce@1532959800 |
| 2018-07-30 16:10:01 |   1532959800 | boson  | wwn-0x50014ee6055a237b |    48 | wwn-0x50014ee6055a237b@1532959800 |
| 2018-07-30 16:10:01 |   1532959800 | boson  | wwn-0x50026b723c0d6dd5 |    51 | wwn-0x50026b723c0d6dd5@1532959800 |
| 2018-07-30 16:10:01 |   1532959800 | boson  | wwn-0x50014ee605a043e2 |    47 | wwn-0x50014ee605a043e2@1532959800 |
| 2018-07-30 16:10:01 |   1532959800 | boson  | wwn-0x50014ee60507b79c |    47 | wwn-0x50014ee60507b79c@1532959800 |
| 2018-07-30 16:15:01 |   1532960100 | boson  | wwn-0x50014ee605a043e2 |    47 | wwn-0x50014ee605a043e2@1532960100 |
| 2018-07-30 16:15:01 |   1532960100 | boson  | wwn-0x50026b723c0d6dd5 |    51 | wwn-0x50026b723c0d6dd5@1532960100 |
| 2018-07-30 16:15:01 |   1532960100 | boson  | wwn-0x50014ee60507b79c |    47 | wwn-0x50014ee60507b79c@1532960100 |
| 2018-07-30 16:15:01 |   1532960100 | boson  | wwn-0x50014ee6055a237b |    48 | wwn-0x50014ee6055a237b@1532960100 |
+---------------------+--------------+--------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------+
```

From this data I make temperature trendgraphs. To get the data in the right format I use this query:

```
SELECT  
  MIN(d1.sample_epoch), 
  AVG(d1.diskt) AS sdd, 
  AVG(d2.diskt) AS hda, 
  AVG(d3.diskt) AS hdb, 
  AVG(d4.diskt) AS hdc, 
  AVG(d5.diskt) AS hdd  
FROM
  disktemp d1,  
  disktemp d2,  
  disktemp d3,  
  disktemp d4,  
  disktemp d5   
WHERE   
  (d1.sample_time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) 
  AND (d1.host = 'boson') 
    AND d1.sample_epoch = d2.sample_epoch 
    AND d1.sample_epoch = d3.sample_epoch 
    AND d1.sample_epoch = d4.sample_epoch 
    AND d1.sample_epoch = d5.sample_epoch 
    AND (d1.diskid LIKE '%d6dd5'  
        AND d2.diskid LIKE '%20fce' 
        AND d3.diskid LIKE '%043e2' 
        AND d4.diskid LIKE '%a237b' 
        AND d5.diskid LIKE '%7b79c' 
        )   
GROUP BY (d1.sample_epoch DIV 5)
;
```

which produces this output:

```
+----------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|           1532960700 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532961000 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532961300 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532961600 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532961900 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532962200 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532962500 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532962800 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532963100 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532963400 | 51.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532963700 | 52.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
|           1532964000 | 53.0000 | 47.0000 | 47.0000 | 48.0000 | 47.0000 |
+----------------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

that I can then take to `gnuplot` for graphing. The value for the `host` is inserted dynamically using a bash-script.

[image: Graphs that look a bit like this]

Now, that's all well and good. But, recently I added an additional server and it doesn't have five disks. So this query doesn't work for that host. Also (I realisedd) when I exchange a disk the `diskid` in the query will have to be changed.

REQUEST:
I'd like some help putting together a query that returns the `diskt` (rows) for each `diskid` (columns) of a given host over a given interval.

I've found these questions seem to look like what I'm trying to do but I have not been able to get a working query out of that. Mostly, I think, because my SQL-fu is not strong enough yet.

Effectively, I'm trying to build dynamic pivot table or cross-table.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397666/split-column-values-into-multiple-columns-with-create-view
2. [query generate the information one column in two columns in one query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22339/query-generate-the-information-one-column-in-two-columns-in-one-query)

Comment: Does it matter to you what the column names of your final table are? To be sure, you need the epoch column and one column for each unique hard drive? I see you have them assigned names based on 5 known drives.  How do you run the queries? Is it run from a script, a mysql tool or straight up mysql command line interface?

Comment: [Here's an example on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns)

Comment: column names are not important.

Comment: @StevenHibble : That one, I had not found yet. I'll check it out.

Comment: A potential flaw:  What if there is a missing entry for `MIN(d1.sample_epoch)` for some disktemp?

Comment: That is very unlikely. The program feeding the data always feeds all disktemperatures in one commit. If one is missing (for some weird reason) all will be absent.

Comment: @AuntJemima : I use a bash script to run the queries. I also have Python3 at my disposal.